# Prevent other hooks from firing after wp_update_post() outside of editor

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, actions, wp-update-post

I'm working on a plugin that batch updates post content using a call to `wp_update_post()`. This all happens outside the editor window, in a batch processing script.
My problem is that ACF is firing after I run the `wp_update_post()` call as I think its because of the `save_post` hooks that run.

This is blanking all my ACF meta, as the values are not present in the post array at that point in time, so how can I prevent anything else firing on this call?

I've tried `remove_all_actions('save_post')` and `remove_all_actions('acf/save_post')` just before the call but its not having any effect.

```
$updated_post = array(
                    'ID' => $current_id,
                    'post_content' => $post_content,
                );
remove_all_actions('save_post');
$result = wp_update_post($updated_post, true);
```

Ideally I'd like to use a wordpress api function to update the content, as it will create a revision, whereas a direct SQL update will not.

Comment: Why not provide the full data? I see at lest 7 action calls and multiple filter calls in `wp_insert_post()` (which is used under the hood). Debugging this will likely be a PITA and prone to errors, as there are many ways to add custom logic in there.

Comment: I see what you are saying about the wp_insert_post() call being a PITA. I might rethink this.

I only need to modify the post_content, and nothing else. I've had to limit the main query to just ID's as pulling in the complete data set for all posts kill the server, plus I'd just be pulling it all out to not modify it, and reinsert it, it seems unnecessary.

I'm using the https://github.com/gdarko/wp-batch-processing and the initial batch setup method pulls in ALL ids, to later process as a batch. There is an insane amount of related post_meta.